# How to hide Menu Popup below on Menu?

Tags: android

I have used navigation drawer with toolbar.On toolbar I have used 3 menu items on toolbar when I press on menu it shows 3 button. I don't want to show these button to user by pressing menu. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image: layout indicating my problem]

Comment: how are you setting the items in the toolbar?

Comment: Please add example code; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You Just Need to Change in Your Menu XML file.

Things you have to change are:

On which menu item click you are getting this popup

1) Change its app:showAsAction

```
 app:showAsAction="always"
```

2) Set your own icon to this item

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```